# How can I sum two values and store the result in other variable?

Tags: calculations, dimension-expressions

In LaTeX2e,how can I sum two values and assign them to other variable?

I want to compute something like:

```
var=\textwidth - 1cm
```

And if both were constants:

```
var=1+1
```

Comment: Please explain your intention. `\textwidth` is also constant. Or do you mean number vs. dimension?

Comment: Depending on where you want to use it, there might be different options (pure TeX, TikZ/PGF, Lua, etc.)

Comment: @Marco my intention is use the result.

Comment: Why do you use the tag `plain-tex` together with `latex3`?

Comment: There is a difference between the length `1cm` and the constant `1`, the latter being anything from text, to a number, to a counter.

Comment: @LeoLiu because I don't know how that can be solved. Could be a latex expression or a plain tex expression or both.

Comment: @voodoomsr: The current version of LaTeX is LaTeX2e, not LaTeX3. LaTeX3 is in development and only a few experimental functions are available. Since Plain TeX and LaTeX are totally different TeX formats, you can't use them together. If you are using LaTeX, you don't need to use any tag for this, and don't use `latex3` tag if you are not using it.

Comment: @LeoLiu thanks Leo I wasn't clear that tex and latex can't be mixed, so I'm going to retag the question

Answer (score 118, accepted):

In regular LaTeX, the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) allows for easy manipulation of length arithmetic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\newlength{\mylength}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\mylength}{\textwidth}%
\noindent\rule{\mylength}{20pt}

\bigskip
\setlength{\mylength}{\textwidth-1cm}%
\noindent\rule{\mylength}{20pt}

\bigskip
\setlength{\mylength}{\textwidth-80pt+5mm-1bp}%
\noindent\rule{\mylength}{20pt}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lines of different lengths using calc package]

The above deals with lengths. For basic arithmetic using numbers, the [`fp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp). Here is an example using infix notation ([Reverse Polish Notation/RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) is also possible via `\FPupn`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\begin{document}
The following arithmetic is easy:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \FPeval{\result}{clip(5+6)}%
    $5+6=\result$
  \item \FPeval{\result}{round(2+3/5*pi,5)}%
    $2+3/5\times\pi=\result$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Regular arithmetic using fp package]

Answer (score 81):

In classical Knuth TeX,

```
\newdimen\len
\len=\hsize
\advance\len by -1cm

\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1
\advance\cnt by 1
```

---

eTeX,

```
\newdimen\len
\len=\dimexpr\hsize-1cm\relax

\newcount\cnt
\cnt=\numexpr1+1\relax
```

---

LaTeX with `calc`,

```
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\len
\setlength{\textwidth+1cm}

\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{1+1}
```

---

LaTeX2e with `expl3` (LaTeX3),

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \l_len_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l_len_dim {\textwidth + 1cm}

\int_new:N \l_cnt_int
\int_set:Nn \l_cnt_int {1+1}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: I'm using LaTeX with calc, and want to use in second argument of \setcounter other counter value, but got an error. Is there a way to calculate value based on other counter?

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn: Use `\value{countername}`.

Answer (score 39):

Since LuaTeX is available, forget all that complicated stuff and do something like:

```
\directlua{
a = 0
a = a + 1

tex.print(a)
}
```

Comment: How would one adapt this approach to deal with length variables, rather than scalars?

Answer (score 26):

In LaTeX, if you just want to subtract one known length (say, `1cm`) from another (say, `\textwidth`) to obtain a new length variable, you can do so using the `\newlength`, `\setlength`, and `\addtolength` instructions, as in the following example:

```
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength\textwidth
\addtolength\mylength{-1cm} %% note the minus sign
```

Comment: Good and simple solution, but I prefer to wrap the command names in curly brackets to make it clearer.

Comment: @erickrf: Thanks for this feedback. In the cod I provided, using or omitting the curly braces around the macros are entirely equivalent. Feel free to use whichever method you feel provides more clarity (or, equivalently, less ambiguity). :-)

Answer (score 14):

With a fairly recent TeX distribution

```
\newdimen\len
\len=\dimexpr\textwidth-1cm\relax

\newcount\cnt
\cnt=\numexpr1+1\relax
```

It's not quite clear what's the framework you're interested in, though.

Answer (score 13):

This is a bit overkill for the particular examples that you mention, but since this works for more complicated expressions I tend to use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\var}{\textwidth - 1cm}

The value of var is \var
\end{document}
```

Note that with `pgfmathsetmacro` the result is a decimal without units.  If you are only interested in lengths, then you can use a similar macro `\pgfmathsetlength`.

---

If you want to minimize what gets loaded and still use `pgfmath`, then see [Is it possible to load pgfmath without loading the full pgf package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22779/is-it-possible-to-load-pgfmath-without-loading-the-full-pgf-package)

Answer (score 10):

I often use the `tikz` package for its wide range of capabilities; consider the following:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

textwidth = \the\textwidth 

\tikzmath{
    \resultone = \textwidth - 1cm;
}

textwidth - 1cm = \resultone


\tikzmath{
    \resulttwo = 1 + 1;  % default type is float
    %
    integer \resultthree;  % declare a variable as an integer
    \resultthree = 1 + 1;
}

1 + 1 as float  = \resulttwo\\
1 + 1 as integer = \resultthree

\end{document}
```

produces the following:

`textwidth = 345.0pt
textwidth - 1cm = 316.54726
1 + 1 as float = 2.0
1 + 1 as integer = 2`

More information can be found in the [pgf/tikz manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) in the chapter for the Math Library.

Comment: +1, and welcome to TeX.SE! The value of `\resultone` appears to be a scalar, not a length variable. Can you modify the code so that `\resultone` contains a length variable?

Answer (score 7):

this helped me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

$12.5+13.8 = \fpeval{12.5+13.8} $

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the `adjcalc` package which is a sub-package of `adjustbox` used to abstract the different calculation backends (eTeX, calc, pgfmath) to a common interface. Which backend is used can be selected by package options.

```
\usepackage{adjcalc} % or {adjustbox}
\newdimen\lengthmacro
\adjsetlength{\lengthmacro}{\textwidth-1cm}
```