# Parse simple arithmetics and return the result

Tags: programming, calculations

I want a command `\ca` which takes a simple arithmetic calculation as an argument and returns the result with proper decimal places. Additionally I want an boolean argument which decides if only the result is printed or the whole calculation.

For example

`\ca{8.12 - 2.2 + 1}`

should just print 6.92.

or

`\ca[t]{8.12 - 2.2 + 1}`

should print 8.12 - 2.2 + 1 = 6.92

Following the question [How can I sum two values and store the result in other variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30081/how-can-i-sum-two-values-and-store-the-result-in-other-variable) I did this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\ca}[2][f]{
\FPeval{\result}{clip(#2)}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{t}}{
$#2=  \result$}
{
\result
}
}



\begin{document}
\ca[t]{3*(2.2 + 2.3)}

\ca{2.5 + 2.78}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to to the same such that the german comma notation is used in what is displayed (i.e. 8,2 instead of 8.2) and in the case the calculation is printed that * is printed as `\dcot`.

Comment: Please take a look at [How can I sum two values and store the result in other variable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30081/how-can-i-sum-two-values-and-store-the-result-in-other-variable) as the answers there might help you. If they do, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If they don't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: As @Werner says, the basics of the calculation are probably covered elsewhere. Something like the Boolean you ask about would be handled by absorbing the argument, doing the calculation then deciding what to print based on a switch. There are questions about that here too, or you might ask something focussed just on the one issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Werner's suggestion helped, I will change my question to address the remaining obscurities

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13333/macros-with-as-the-last-parameter, I have a similar example in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a crude way of modifying the output to be `\cdot` and `,`-specific using [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring). The reason for using `xstring` is because the argument to [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) (`#2`) would otherwise have to be parsed and separated into operators and operands to enable [`numprint`](http://ctan.org/pkg/numprint) usage (say).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse

\NewDocumentCommand{\ca}{s m}{
  \FPeval{\result}{clip(#2)}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% Condition on starred/unstarred version
    {% starred version \ca*{...}
      \StrSubstitute{\result}{.}{,}
    }{% unstarred version \ca{...}
      \StrSubstitute{#2}{.}{,\!}[\temp]% '.' -> ','
      \StrSubstitute{\temp}{*}{\cdot}[\temp]% '*' -> '\cdot'
      $\temp=\StrSubstitute{\result}{.}{,\!}$
    }
}

\begin{document}
\ca{3*(2.2 + 2.3)}

\ca*{2.5 + 2.78}
\end{document}​
```

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) was used to provide a starred/unstarred version of `\ca` where the unstarred version `\ca` prints the expression, while the starred version `\ca*` does not.

Answer (score 7):

I think you mean `\cdot` not `\dot`. In this case you may use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begingroup
\catcode`\.=\active
\catcode`\*=\active
\newcommand{\germannotation}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\.=\active
    \def.{{,}}%
    \catcode`\*=\active
    \def*{\cdot}%
    \scantokens{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\global\let\germannotation\germannotation
\endgroup

\newcommand{\ca}[2][f]{%
  \FPeval{\result}{clip(#2)}%
  \edef\result{\noexpand\germannotation{\result}}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{t}}{%
    $\germannotation{#2}=\result$%
  }{%
    \result
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\ca[t]{3*(2.2 + 2.3)}

\ca{2.5 + 2.78}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice - this is great!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a version that use `pgf` for the math calculations which allows for more complicated math expressions (such as `tan(deg(pi/4))` below), and [the `numprint` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/numprint/) for the formatting of the output:

[image]

### Notes:

- The german formatting of the input and changing the `*` in the input to a `\cdot` (adding `pi`, `\tan`, etc...) is adapted form @Werner's solution.

### Futher Enhancements:

- Use `numprint` for the numbers in the input as that allows for more flexibility than just changing the `.` to a `,`.
- Handle formatting of more complex mathematical expressions, for instance change `exp(a/b)` to `\e^{a/b}`

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{numprint}

\newcommand*{\AdjustInput}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{.}{,\!}[\temp]%
    \StrSubstitute{\temp}{*}{\cdot}[\temp]% 
    \StrSubstitute{\temp}{sin}{\sin}[\temp]% 
    \StrSubstitute{\temp}{cos}{\cos}[\temp]% 
    \StrSubstitute{\temp}{tan}{\tan}[\temp]% 
    \StrSubstitute{\temp}{deg}{}[\temp]% 
    \StrSubstitute{\temp}{((}{(}[\temp]% 
    \StrSubstitute{\temp}{))}{)}[\temp]% 
    \StrSubstitute{\temp}{pi}{\pi}[\temp]% 
    \temp%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\ca}{s m}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\var}{#2}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \ensuremath{\numprint{\var}}%
    }{%
        \ensuremath{\AdjustInput{#2}=\numprint{\var}}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\ca*{8.12 - 2.2 + 1}% starred version only prints result

\ca{3*(2.2 + 2.3)}

\ca{8.12 - 2.2 + tan(deg(pi/4))}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you see, I can use `\ensuremath` sometimes. :)

Comment: @egreg: :-) I saw that in you answer, but was waiting to see if you would recommend I remove it here. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill: Note though that your expression still does not show commas since `\numprint` is only applied to the answer.

Comment: @Werner: I did not read that that was required by the OP, but have adapted your solution for that.

Answer (score 5):

This is a simplified version of Schweinebacke's solution (and a case where `\ensuremath` can be justified):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse,fp}
\def\changecommaandstar{%
  \mathcode`.=\string"8000
  \mathcode`*=\string"8000
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{{,}}
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`*\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\cdot}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ca}{sm}{%
  \ensuremath{\begingroup
  \FPeval{\result}{clip(#2)}
  \changecommaandstar                   
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{#2=}\result
  \endgroup}
}

\begin{document}

\ca*{3*(2.2 + 2.3)}

$\ca{2.5 + 2.78}>5$

\end{document}
```

This is also a case where a *-version, rather than an optional argument, is perhaps better.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little hesitant in adding this answer, as I'm merely fumbling my way around with Lua. Feel free to edit and improve the code.

Anyways, as implied above, here is a way that requires compilation with `lualatex`, as the calculation is done with Lua.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\newcommand{\ca}[2][f]{%
\luaexec{
    check = "#1"
    input = #2
    answer = tostring(input)
    answer = string.gsub(answer, "\%.", "{,}")
    calculation = "#2"
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "*", "\\cdot ")
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "\%.", "{,}")
    if check == "f" then
       tex.sprint("\\ensuremath{", answer, "}")
    else
       tex.sprint("\\ensuremath{", calculation, "=", answer, "}")
    end
}}
\begin{document}
\ca{1+2.2 - 5/2} \par
\ca[t]{3+1-2.34*3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This could also be expanded to allow `sin`, `cos`, etc. by changing the definition of the command to

```
\newcommand{\ca}[2][f]{%
\luaexec{
    local sin, cos, tan, pi, exp, ln, log = math.sin, math.cos, math.tan, math.pi, math.exp, math.log, math.log10
    check = "#1"
    input = #2
    answer = tostring(input)
    answer = string.gsub(answer, "\%.", "{,}")
    calculation = "#2"
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "*", "\\cdot ")
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "\%.", "{,}")
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "pi*", "\\pi ")
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "sin", "\\sin ")
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "cos", "\\cos ")
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "tan", "\\tan ")
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "exp", "\\exp ")
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "ln", "\\ln ")
    calculation = string.gsub(calculation, "log", "\\log ")
    if check == "f" then
       tex.sprint("\\ensuremath{", answer, "}")
    else
       tex.sprint("\\ensuremath{", calculation, "=", answer, "}")
    end
}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is something I fooled around with. I became aware of your question afterwards, so it is only a partial answer. It uses the new `l3fp` package of `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \typeset_eq:n #1 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_tl \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpb_tl { * } { \times }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpb_tl { pi } { \pi }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpb_tl { sin } { \sin }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpb_tl { cos } { \cos }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpb_tl { tan } { \tan }
  $
  \l_tmpb_tl = \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl }
  $
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \eq } { m } {
  \typeset_eq:n { #1 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\eq{ 1 + 2 * 3 }

\eq{ sin ( pi / 3 ) }

\eq{ cos ( pi / 4 ) }

\eq{ tan ( pi / 6 ) }

\end{document}
```

[image]