# Increment/display the content of a (variable)/(section number) under latex?

Tags: arithmetic

To have something equivalent to echo of the shell. For instance in .tex file we have:

```
 \def \var{2}

    The content of var is $var
```

How to edit the tex file in such a way we have as output:

**The content of var is 2**?

Especially, can we perform arithmetic operations under latex? Say

```
var = var + x
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30081

Comment: (La)TeX can calculate stuff, but it is meant for typesetting. Depending on what you want to do, Lua would be the better alternative.

Comment: In fact, I need to enumerate some sections but without using itemize or the like. I need to add a number before some sections and this number needs to increment.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `section` and should not implement stuff on your own. If you really want to do it yourself, `stepcounter` and `refstepcounter` are the commands to use with LaTeX2e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\var}{2}
\newcommand*{\x}{5}

\begin{document}
    The content of \verb|\var| is \var

    $\var+\x = \the\numexpr\var+\x\relax$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**:

In your comment to your question, you ask something quite different. This could be done like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{mycounter}{42}
    \themycounter{} My Section Starting where I Want
    \stepcounter{mycounter}

    \themycounter{} And Here Comes the Next Section 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Should I reformulate my question?

Comment: @polar Glad I could help. If you think, this post will help others in future, you could rewrite your question a bit. Or just change the title. Like it stands now, it will be a bit confusing. Don't know... if you think, everything has been answered already on this site, you could also think about deleting it. Whatever you want.