# adding two lengths in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to add two tikz dimensions, like so

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newdimen\heya
    \newdimen\xtra
    \xtra=0.3cm
    \heya=4cm+\xtra
    \draw (0,0) -- (\heya, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The line `\heya=4cm+\xtra` causes an error. What's the right way to do this?

Thanks!

=======

UPDATE: See Steven's answer below.

I found it easier to create a macro, *à la*

```
\newcommand{\add}[2]{\dimexpr#1+#2\relax}
```

and then...

```
\heya=\add{4cm}{\xtra}
```

...works as desired!

Comment: [How can I sum two values and store the result in other variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30085/124842)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing to do with `tikz` but the TeX primitive `\dimexpr` (terminated by a unexpandable token such as `\relax`) allows dimensional math calculations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newdimen\heya
    \newdimen\xtra
    \xtra=0.3cm
    \heya=\dimexpr4cm+\xtra\relax
    \draw (0,0) -- (\heya, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Within `tikz`, calculations can be done in braces, such as `{\xtra+4cm}`.  As  Torbjørn T. points out, the braces are optional if the argument has no parentheses, but it may be just easier to place them there to avoid the risk of a future edit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newdimen\heya
    \newdimen\xtra
    \xtra=0.3cm
    \draw (0,0) -- ({\xtra+4cm}, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking the braces in your last example aren't needed, but they are required if the expression contains parentheses, e.g. `({sin(90)},0)`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I created a macro `\add{#1}{#2}` for `\dimexpr#1+#2\relax` which should make it even easier on my brain in future...

Comment: @Labrador You just have to be careful when using `\def`ed variables instead of length variables, if negatives are involved: `-\dimexpr-2cm\relax` is `2cm`, but `--2cm` is not.

Comment: technically it's ε-TeX primitive