# Is there a possibility of writing length or width of measurements in latex as a sum or difference of 2 or more values

Tags: width, lengths

I wish to know if there exist a way in latex of writing the length or width of something as a sum or difference of 2 or more measurements e.g

1. \parskip + \baselineskip, and/or
2. \textheight - 5\parskip?

Comment: read dimexpr in etex_man.pdf, or dim_eval:n in interface3.pdf

Comment: e.g. [adding two lengths in tikz - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399534/adding-two-lengths-in-tikz)

Comment: `\dimexpr \parskip + \baselineskip + \textheight - 5\parskip`