# Division in Latex -I'm getting incorrect values-How to perform division correctly

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I'm trying to perform a division and sometimes it works and other times I get and unexpected value.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\coeff{5}
\newcommand\addend{13}
\newcommand\result{45}
\newcommand\exaddend{\the\numexpr\addend*\coeff}
\newcommand\resultrest{\the\numexpr\result-\exaddend}
\begin{align*}
        \coeff x+\exaddend&=\result \\
        -\exaddend&=-\exaddend\\
        \coeff x&=\resultrest\\
        \frac{\cancel{\coeff}x}{\cancel{\coeff}}&=\frac{\resultrest}{\coeff}\\
        x&=\boxed{\the\numexpr\resultrest/\coeff\relax}
        \end{align*}\vspace{1em} 
\end{document}
```

It works if I use fixed values:
It seems the last line `\the\numexpr\resultrest/\coeff\relax`  seems to produce the issue.  Please help!

Comment: Although your code seems to compile properly, but you are including many unnecessary commands and format. As a start, you may remove `$` symbol, before `\begin{aligned}` and after `\end{aligned}`.

Comment: I can also see no need for the triple successive environment `\begin{enumerate} \item \begin{flushleft} $\begin{aligned}`. Perhaps `\begin{align}` or `\begin{align*}` if you need no equations numbering are enough.

Comment: If you want align your equations left, you can use `fleqn` option in your class, e.g.,  `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}`.

Comment: Yes thank you @hesham.  That works a lot better.

Comment: For the arithmetic calculation part, you may check out this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30083/91556 at the second part of `fp` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `\extatend` and `\resultrest` with unterminated `\numexpr` (no `\relax`), so when you use them in another `\numexpr`, the expression is effectively inserted literally, so you may evaluate `5-1/2` when you intended `(5-1)/2`. I suggest you put `\relax` at the end of both `\extatend` and `\resultrest`.

Other alternatives are to define them including parentheses, or if you want only a single fixed value, define them using `\edef`.

You don't say what unexpected value you get for which input, so there remains the possibility that you just didn't expect integer division.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Can you point me to how to use \edef ?  I'm am unfamiliar and learning.

Comment: Welcome! `\edef` is basic TeX; it is something like `\newcommand` but "expands" its definition. This is complicated, because "expansion" is a deep detail of TeX, in that some operations are "expandable" and others not, sometimes without obvious reason (`\numexpr` evaluation is expandable). Go ahead and dive into TeX reading The TeXbook or TeX by Topic, but it is a journey. `\numexpr` is even an extension of TeX, but has its own odd details, like being delimited by `\relax`.                 `\edef\exaddend{\the\numexpr\addend*\coeff\relax}`

Comment: (The journey is by swimming, if you follow that mixed metaphor.) Remember, adding `\relax` to the end of the `\newcommand` is sufficient; you don't need `\edef`.