# Random form letter text

Tags: random-numbers

I want to randomize some of the text contained within some letters. For e.g.:

```
\random{Dear \name,}{Hello \name,}{Greetings \name,}{Hi \name,}{To \name,}
\random{You are invited to}{You are welcome to}{I would like to invite you to}{This is an invitation to}{You may want to} attend...
```

When compiled, this would randomly select one of the phrases to use, so that each of the letters is a bit different. How can this be done?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38599/the-effect-of-the-anonymous-letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an implementation for four arguments based on Marc's answer.
It uses `\ifcase` instead of `\ifodd`. Because `random(4)` returns 1--4, but `\ifcase` starts from 0, the first case is actually kept empty.
If more than four arguments are wanted simple change `[4]` and `(4)` to a higher number and add `\or#5` etc. However, more than 9 arguments needs extra work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand*{\random}[4]{%
    \pgfmathparse{random(4)}%
    \ifcase\pgfmathresult\relax
      \or#1\or#2\or#3\or#4%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
% Tests:
\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\random{1}{2}{3}{4}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the very experimental [`l3rand` package](http://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/l3trial/l3rand) (currently in the `l3trial` directory of the LaTeX3 code repository, which means it is *really* not stable), you can do the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3rand,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\rand_seed_from_time:
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_item:nn { nf }
\DeclareDocumentCommand {\random} {m}
  {
    \tl_item:nf {#1} { \rand_range:nn {0} { \tl_length:n {#1} - 1 } }
    \rand_clean:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\name}{Dave}
\random { {Dear \name,} {Hello \name,} {Greetings \name,} {Hi \name,} {To \name,} }
\random { {You are invited to} {You are welcome to} {I would like to invite you to} {This is an invitation to} {You may want to} }
attend...
\end{document}
```

Currently, `\rand_range:nn {`*`<begin>`*`} {`*`<end>`*`}` produces a random number between *`<begin>`* and *`<end>`* inclusive, hence the need to subtract 1. This may very well be changed later. Also, `\rand_seed_from_time:` might be renamed by the time this solution is used by anyone.

I added braces around the whole argument of `\random`, otherwise TeX has no easy way of knowing where it ends.

Comment: You need to define `\newcommand*{\name}{Dave}` :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. Why Dave? Also, should `l3rand` initialize with a random seed by default, letting the user override it with `\rand_seed:n { <int> }`, or should it favor reproducibility, with the user typing `\rand_seed_from_time:` explicitly if he wants random initialization?

Comment: Now `\tl_length:n` should be replaced by `\tl_count:n` (not doing the change now, since this would bump the answer on the front page, and `l3rand` is still as experimental as always).

Answer (score 4):

The following should do the trick. For some reason I cannot get it to work without loading the entire tikz package (pgfmath *should* have sufficed).

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\random}[2]{%
    \pgfmathparse{random(2)}%
    \ifodd\pgfmathresult\relax#1\else#2\fi%
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: See [Is it possible to load pgfmath without loading the full pgf package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22779/is-it-possible-to-load-pgfmath-without-loading-the-full-pgf-package) for an explanation about the issues with loading `pgfmath` alone. These are fixed in the current develop version. As a workaround loading the `pgf` package is enough, no need to load the full higher-level `tikz` layer.

Comment: @joseph Thanks for your comment. I'm still learning the interface.

Comment: Your solution has a flaw: `\ifodd` will expand all tokens behind it until it finds something which is not part of a number. Because `\pgfmathresult` holds a single digit only the content of `#1` is searched for a potential rest of this number. This leads to that e.g. `\random{1 always}{never}` always picks the first argument, because the `1` is appended to the result, making it always odd. You need to terminate the numerical input of `\ifodd` explicitly either using a `\relax` or a `\space` behind `\pgfmathresult`.