# square root of number in counter

Tags: counters, calculations

I would like to get the square root of a number which I have stored into a counter. I have been using the [calc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) package for summation and multiplication operations, but I cannot find anything like

```
\setcounter{squarerootofmynumber}{\value{mynumber}^{1/2}}
```

or something like that. Do you know the way?

Comment: Counters can only store integer values.

Comment: As pointed out by @egreg counters can only store integers. I'm not aware of a package that helps approximating squre roots. What do you need this for?

Comment: There are a range of packages that let you calculate square roots ([`expl3`'s `l3fp` module](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel), [`calculator`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calculator), [`fp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp)) but that won't help for storing the results in a counter for the reasons already mentioned.

Comment: With `\usepackage{pgf}`, you can use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\squarerootofmynumber}{sqrt(\value{mynumber})}`.

Answer (score 23):

Here are four ways for calculating the square root of a number (with varying precision). However, the result cannot be stored in a counter unless it is an integer.

1. The [`calculator`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calculator) package

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{calculator}
   \newcounter{mycount}
   \setcounter{mycount}{7}
   \begin{document}
   \SQUAREROOT{\themycount}{\solution}%
   $\sqrt{\themycount}=\solution$
   \end{document}
   ```
2. The [`fp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp) package

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fp}
   \newcounter{mycount}
   \setcounter{mycount}{7}
   \begin{document}
   \FProot\solution{\themycount}{2}%
   \FPround\solution\solution{5}%
   $\sqrt{\themycount}=\solution$
   \end{document}
   ```
3. The [`pgf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package (thanks to Peter Grill for the reminder)

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pgf}
   \newcounter{mycount}
   \setcounter{mycount}{7}
   \begin{document}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\solution}{sqrt(\themycount)}%
   $\sqrt{\themycount}=\solution$
   \end{document}
   ```
4. The `l3fp` module of the [`l3kernel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel)

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{expl3}
   \ExplSyntaxOn
   \cs_new_eq:NN \calculate \fp_eval:n
   \ExplSyntaxOff
   \newcounter{mycount}
   \setcounter{mycount}{7}
   \begin{document}
   $\sqrt{\themycount}=\calculate{round(sqrt(\themycount),5)}$
   \end{document}
   ```

All of these examples give

[image]

Storing the result in a counter requires the result to be an integer. Packages 2-4 have means to round a result which would allow to set a counter afterwards. Here is an example with `l3fp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \calculate \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{7}
\edef\solution{\calculate{round(sqrt(\value{mycount}),0)}}
\setcounter{mycount}{\solution}\themycount
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can `\usepackage{pgfmath}` if you only want the calc features, and not the whole drawing engine. Perhaps also is worth to mention that if you have `tikz` or `beamer`, then `pgfmath` is already loaded.

Comment: @JLDiaz I tried that with the example above but it gave `! Undefined control sequence. l.108 \pgfkeys` and I was to lazy to investigate why that was...

Comment: You are right. Then it does not work as advertised in the manual :(

Comment: Nice answer. As far as `pgfmath` see: [Is it possible to load pgfmath without loading the full pgf package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22779/is-it-possible-to-load-pgfmath-without-loading-the-full-pgf-package).

Answer (score 17):

a solution with `lualatex` with a good precision

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcounter{mycount} \setcounter{mycount}{7}
\begin{document}

\directlua{tex.print(math.sqrt(\themycount))}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using the `sqrt` function which is provided with the [xintexpr](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) package you can calculate square roots with arbitrary precisions.

I have updated this answer to illustrate use of the new `[P]` optional argument to `\xintfloatexpr` (v1.1) and rounded integral square root in `\xintiiexpr` (v1.1a).

Also, one can use directly the underlying macros from packages [xint and xintfrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint). See the documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\begin{document}

$\sqrt{17}$ with various precisions:


% Square root with 16 digits of precision:
\xintthefloatexpr sqrt(17)\relax

% If you have a LaTeX counter, use \value:
\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{17}

% \xintthefloatexpr sqrt(\value{cnt})\relax

% Square root with more digits:
\xintthefloatexpr [24] sqrt(17,24)\relax
% The 24 is needed twice, once for sqrt to compute with 
%  24 digits, and once for \xintthefloatexpr not to
%  round to only 16 digits.
% The [24] requires xintexpr v1.1 or later.

% Or change globally the precision:
\xintDigits := 48;
\xintthefloatexpr sqrt(17)\relax

% There is a variant which works only with (big) integers.
% You can use choose between sqrt which truncates and sqrtr
% which rounds. The latter requires xintexpr v1.1a or later.

Integer approximation to $\sqrt{170000000000000000}$:

\xinttheiiexpr sqrt(170000000000000000)\relax{} (truncated using \verb|sqrt|)

\xinttheiiexpr sqrtr(170000000000000000)\relax{} (rounded using \verb|sqrtr|)% v1.1a or later

% This can be put in a LaTeX counter if <2^31.

A counter can not hold larger than $\number"7FFFFFFF$.

\setcounter{cnt}{\xinttheiiexpr sqrtr(170000000000000000)\relax}
The counter holds: $\thecnt\approx \sqrt{170000000000000000}$.

\setcounter{cnt}{\xinttheiiexpr sqrtr(1700000000000000000)\relax}
The counter holds $\thecnt\approx \sqrt{1700000000000000000}$.

% Rather than expressions with the function sqrt, one
% can also use directly the underlying macros provided 
% by xint and xintfrac package. See xint documentation.
\end{document}
```

[image: square roots]