# Undefined control sequence error for \pgfkeys when using pgfmath package

Tags: pgfmath

Why does this MWE result in an error?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{atan2(5,2)}
\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

From what I've read in the documentation, I've loaded all the appropriate packages.  In particular, on page 525, the manual says that if I don't want the full package of `pgf` then I can just load `pgfmath`.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Is it possible to load pgfmath without loading the full pgf package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22779) (the answer there still works.)

Comment: @AlanMunn I guess so.  Feel free to mark as duplicate.  When I did my search I did not find the referenced page because I didn't formulate my question that way.  So I'll leave this question here so that other can get redirected.

Comment: @AlanMunn If I write `\pgfmathatantwo` I get an undefined control sequence error.  Even when I followed the linked solution.

Comment: @A.Ellett: After loading `tikz` the command `\pgfmathatantwo` doesn't work either. I guess it's a bug of `pgf`.

Comment: @A.Ellett: http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/209/#9dd5

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your document works if I replace `\usepackage{pgfmath}` with
`\usepackage{pgfkeys}`
`\input{pgfutil-common}`
`\input{pgfmath.code}`

Comment: Leo is pointing you to the bug report that shows that the `\pgfmathatantwo` macro doesn't work.  But the alternative syntax in your sample document *does* work.

Comment: @alanmunn this is extremely frustrating.  I'm tring to learn `tikz` and the features it provides, but it's just too buggy.  I tried following @PaulGaborit 's [suggestion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63982/22413) about how to update to the most current cvs version, but I get compilation errors.

Comment: I'm not sure I would characterize it as too buggy. Plenty of people use it extensively every day without problems. This is not to say that it's bug-free, just that it's a pretty solid piece of software overall.